# Facebook connect FBJS misssing accented characters

Tags: facebook, fbjs

I use FBJS FB.Connect.streamPublish. The content of 'What's on your mind?' field is filled by my code and includes accented characters. On IE it appears fine. On FireFox the accented character do not show.

alert (message) on the message shows that it does include the missing character but it does not show up on FB dialog.

Any advice on how to solve this?

Thanks.
Niro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the first parameter of FB.Connect.streamPublish needs to be in UTF8 in Firefox to display accented characters. Converting to UTF8 can be achived like this:
unicodestr =unescape( encodeURIComponent( str ));

Note it is needed only for Firefox, Chrome and Safari and will mess the string in IE.